# Generics and ormlite

Tags: java, generics, ormlite

This is mostly a Java Generics issue, but how can I do something like this:

```
class BaseClass {
    public void save() {
        OrmLiteInstance.getDao(getClass()).createOrUpdate(this)
    }

class B extends BaseClass
class A extends BaseClass
```

This ends up with the error:

```
Error:(61, 58) error: method createOrUpdate in interface Dao<T,ID> cannot be applied
to given types;
required: CAP#1
found: BaseClass
reason: actual argument BaseClass cannot be converted to CAP#1 by method invocation conversion
 where T,ID are type-variables:
 T extends Object declared in interface Dao
 ID extends Object declared in interface Dao
 where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends BaseClass from capture of ? extends BaseClass
```

The signature for the methods are:

```
public <D extends Dao<T, ?>, T> D getDao(Class<T> clazz) throws SQLException
public CreateOrUpdateStatus createOrUpdate(T data) throws SQLException;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs because the method `getClass()`, when called by a type `T`, returns `Class<? extends T>` which is not the same as `Class<T>`.

So your `getDao(getClass())` call is actually returning an instance of parameterized type `D extends Dao<? extends T, ?>` which means that the `createOrUpdate` method is expecting a parameter of type `? extends T`.

In your code example, the call to `getDao(getClass())` returns type `D extends Dao<? extends BaseClass, ?>` and so the call to `createOrUpdate` is expecting an object of type `? extends BaseClass`. But `this` refers to an object of type `BaseClass`. And so the error message is advising you that `BaseClass` is not the same type as `? extends BaseClass` (which it has enigmatically named `CAP#1` for lack of a formal label).

To fix this, try changing the signature of the `getDao` method to the following:

```
public <D extends Dao<T, ?>, T> D getDao(Class<? extends T> clazz);
```

This should correct the mismatch between the generic parameter types.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a suggested method signature. It compiles fine for me using this signature, but I don't have exactly the same infrastructure in place, just a stub structure.

Comment: I inverted the way I was doing  things so this is no longer needed.  Maybe the ormlite team will consider what you posted.